# Can I play Destiny with a 2GB internal hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

Is it possible to buy Destiny on my Xbox 360 that only has a 2GB internal hard drive? I even bought a 2TB Seagate Xbox game drive, but it still says I need a hard drive. Am I just screwed and will never be able to play it with this Xbox?

Answer (score 3):

According to Bungie, with update 2.0.0, (which came out in 2015) you can install base destiny onto a USB drive. 
here is the info from the Bungie Help page:

> With the 2.0.0 update of Destiny, Xbox 360 players can now install the Destiny base game to a USB drive. The USB drive must have 10GB of free space or higher.
>
> When update 2.0.0 is released on September 8, 2015, Xbox 360 players who do not have sufficient free hard drive space will encounter an error after launching Destiny. This error reads, "You do not have sufficient storage space."
>
> To clear up additional hard drive space, the base game of Destiny can be moved to an external USB drive.
>
> Installing Destiny to an external USB drive
>
> 1. Close the Destiny application
> 2. Insert USB drive into console
> 3. Navigate to "System Settings"
> 4. Select "Hard Drive"
> 5. Select "Games and Apps"
> 6. Select "Destiny"
> 7. Select "Destiny (Xbox 360 Game)"
> 8. Select "Move"
> 9. Select the "Memory Unit" with available space
>
> 10.Once the Move is complete, ensure your Hard Drive has over 10GB of free space available
>
> 11.Launch Destiny and the install should automatically prompt after logging in

URL: https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/13478

Comment: USB drives are fairly cheap now a days too.